# Not able to use offsetof with clang compiler using libc++ and C++14

Tags: c++, header, clang

I am trying to install some software on an Ubuntu 14.04 computational server. The server has `gcc` version 4.8.4. And the software refuses to install since the compiler does not support C++14. I tried to sidestep this issue by installing `clang` version 3.9 (which supports C++14) on the server and then recompiling with the `clang` compiler. However, then I got an error from the compiler indicating that it did not recognize the `offsetof` macro (from the `cstddef` include file).

To investigate this issue further, I created this simple test program:

```
#include <cstddef>
struct A {
  int x;
};
int main() {
  int off = (int) offsetof(A, x);
  return 0;
}
```

Then I tried to compile:

```
$ gcc offsetof.cpp -o offsetof 
[No errors]
$ clang++-3.9 offsetof.cpp -o offsetof # using libstdc++
[No errors]
$ clang++-3.9 -std=c++14 offsetof.cpp -o offsetof # using libstdc++
[No errors]
$ clang++-3.9 -stdlib=libc++ offsetof.cpp -o offsetof # using libc++
[No errors]
$ clang++-3.9 -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ offsetof.cpp -o offsetof # using libc++ and C++14
offsetof.cpp:8:28: error: 'A' does not refer to a value
  int off = (int) offsetof(A, x);
                           ^
offsetof.cpp:3:8: note: declared here
struct A {
       ^
offsetof.cpp:8:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
  int off = (int) offsetof(A, x);
                              ^
2 errors generated.
```

By compiling with `-H` option I could determine which header files was used for each case:

- gcc :

  ```
  /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstddef
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
  ```
- clang++3.9 -stdlib=libc++

  ```
  /usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef
  /usr/lib/llvm-3.9/lib/clang/3.9.1/include/stddef.h
  ```
- clang++3.9 (using libstdc++)

  ```
  /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstddef
  /usr/lib/llvm-3.9/lib/clang/3.9.1/include/stddef.h
  ```

**Q**: Why do I get errors when compiling with `clang` and options
 `-std=c++14` and `-stdlib=libc++` ?

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Can you retry with warnings turned on? Also, did you observe any other faults with that compiler/standard/standardlib combination?

Comment: It is strange. It works by me. It looks like a bug in the concrete clang 3.9 or libc++ release. What will happen if you try `int off = (int) offsetof(std::decay_t<A>, x);`?

Comment: @S.M. Then I get error `no member named 'decay_t' in namespace 'std'`

Comment: Add include `#include <type_traits>`

Comment: @S.M. After including `type_traits`, I get error: `expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`

Comment: Where does it find `function-style cast or type construction`? I see only `(int)`.

Comment: @S.M. It indicates that the error is related to this term `std::decay_t<A>`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Adding flag `-Wall` does not give any new information. It just adds a warning about `unused variable 'off'`

Comment: It is definitely something wrong with libc++. What happens if you try `int off = (int) offsetof(std::decay<A>::type, x);`?

Comment: @S.M. Still the same error about missing `(` in cast or type construction..

Comment: `offsetof` calls the builtin. What is the implementation of it in the library of your system?

Comment: @S.M. It is the same implementation in both `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h` and `/usr/lib/llvm-3.9/lib/clang/3.9.1/include/stddef.h`. The definition of the macro is given as: `#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)`

Comment: I do not have Ubuntu 14.04 so I can not help. If you wish you can update clang. The instructions are here https://apt.llvm.org/

Comment: @S.M. Ok I will see what I can do.. Thanks for spending the time and helping me as far as you could!